# Rails 3 - Paperclip - Email Attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, actionmailer

Attempting to email a Paperclip attachment in Rails 3.

Invoice model:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

has_attached_file :attachment,
:url => "http://server/app/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
:path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
validates_attachment_presence :attachment
validates_attachment_size :attachment, :less_than => 5.megabytes

end
```

account_mailer:

```
  def email_approver(invoice)
    @subject          = 'Invoice Approval Request'
    @body["invoice"]  = invoice
    #attachment  "application/octet-stream" do |a|
          #a.body = File.read(invoice.attachment.to_file.path)
          #a.filename = invoice.attachment_file_name
      #end
    @recipients = [invoice.approver_email, invoice.alternate_approver_email].compact
    @from             = "ADMIN"
    @sent_on          = Time.now
    @headers          = {}    
 end
```

error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `filename=' for #<Mail::Part:0x00000002566dd0>):
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tries something like this

```
attachments[invoice.attachment_file_name] = File.read(invoice.attachment.to_file.path)
```

?

Comment: Hi there - sorry for the delay in responding.  Unfortunately, I receive the same error.  I think I'm going to modify the business process to avoid attachments.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but here's my working solution:

```
attachments[mymodel.attachment.filename] = File.read(mymodel.attachment.path)
```